# Create repository based on entity type

Tags: generics, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I would like to create a repository based on the entity type. Any ideas how to do that?

- We have a lot of entities, so this needs to be generic code.
- We need to have history tables for every entity that we have.
- We are using code-first, `DbContext`, EF 5.0 using repository and unit of work patterns.

Below is the code we have to get changes in the `SaveChanges` method. For every modified and deleted entity we would like to save the old row into a history table. Below is hard coded for a single entity:  `ServiceLocation`.

All entities have a corresponding history entity. For example, for the `ServiceLocation` entity there is a `ServiceLocationHistory` entity (and repository).

If the modifiedEntity is of type `ServiceLocation`, how do I create a `ServiceLocationHistoryRepository`? And make it generic for all types?

```
  public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        // Get the entities that changed
        var addedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added && e.Entity is IHistoryBase).Select(e => (TBaseEntity)e.Entity);
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified && e.Entity is IHistoryBase).Select(e => (TBaseEntity)e.Entity);
        var deletedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted && e.Entity is IHistoryBase).Select(e => (TBaseEntity)e.Entity);

        // Debugging watch varibles
        int x = addedEntries.Count();
        int y = modifiedEntries.Count();
        int z = deletedEntries.Count();

        // Create the Type adapter
        TypeAdapter adapter = new TypeAdapter(new RegisterTypesMap[] { new HistoryRegisterTypesMap() });
        var serviceLocationHistoryRepository = new ServiceLocationHistoryRepository(this);

        foreach (var addedEntry in addedEntries)
        {
            addedEntry.FromDate = DateTime.Now;
            addedEntry.ToDate = DateTime.Parse("9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000");
        }

        foreach (var modifiedEntry in modifiedEntries)
        {

            ServiceLocationHistory history = adapter.Adapt<ServiceLocation, ServiceLocationHistory>(modifiedEntry as ServiceLocation);
            serviceLocationHistoryRepository.Add(history);

            history.FromDate = modifiedEntry.FromDate;
            history.ToDate = modifiedEntry.FromDate = DateTime.Now;
            modifiedEntry.ToDate = DateTime.Parse("9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000");
        }

        foreach (var deletedEntry in deletedEntries)
        {
            ServiceLocationHistory history = adapter.Adapt<ServiceLocation, ServiceLocationHistory>(deletedEntry as ServiceLocation);
            serviceLocationHistoryRepository.Add(history);

            history.FromDate = deletedEntry.FromDate;
            history.ToDate = DateTime.Now;
         }
        return base.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the proof of concept code I used to get the repository based on the type.

```
       private dynamic GetHistoryRepository(TBaseEntity entry)
    {
        // TODO - How well does the below perform?
        // TODO - Is there a way that we can only get one repository if there are multiple changed entities of the same type?
        // TODO - How can we not hard code the type name?   Put a property on each entity that gives us the entitys history repository?  Factory?

        // Get the History repository for the entity
        Type objType = Type.GetType("Data.MainBoundedContext.CALMModule.Repositories." + entry.GetType().Name.Split('_')[0] + "HistoryRepository");
        return  Activator.CreateInstance(objType, new object[] { this });
    }
```